# Indented Bill of Materials multiplication in R

Tags: r

I am trying to determine the Qty Needed for a forecast on an indented bill of materials (BOM) to do some inventory control. The BOM has multiple levels for subassemblies so the quantity needed for the parent item needs to get multiplied by each level. For example:

| Item | Level | Quantity.Per | Parent Item | Parent Qty Forecast | Qty Needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finished Item | 0 | 1 | Finished Item | 10 | (1x10) = 10 |
| Subassembly 1 | 1 | 2 | Finished Item | 10 | (1x2x10)=20 |
| Component 1 Subassembly 1 | 2 | 5 | Finished Item | 10 | (1 x 2 x 5 x 10) = 100 |
| Subassembly 2 | 1 | 4 | Finished Item | 10 | (1 x 4 x 10 ) = 40 |
| Component 1 Subassembly 2 | 2 | 2 | Finished Item | 10 | (1 x 4 x 2 x 10 ) = 80 |
| Component 1 Component 1 Subassembly 2 | 3 | 2 | Finished Item | 10 | (1 x 4 x 2 x 2 x 10 ) = 160 |

Is there a way to calculate the qty needed in R for each line of BOM by bringing in the top level quantity per all the way up to the finished item?

Comment: I can see how to tie each row to the top-level parent row (via `Parent Item`), but how  do I know concretely that row 5's immediate parent is row 4?

Comment: I agree, that is a complex issue. The only way to tie it up to the parent is to link it to the level up, so the calculation would stop when level above < level below.

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front: this is fragile: if row order changes at all, it will break ... *silently*. If you have any better way to identify groups and subgroups, it would be good to use them.

However, try this

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Parent.Item) %>%
  group_by(L1 = cumsum(Level == 1), .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    Qty = Parent.Qty.Forecast * sapply(Level, \(lvl) prod(Quantity.Per[Level <= lvl]))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#   Item                                  Level Quantity.Per Parent.Item   Parent.Qty.Forecast    L1   Qty
#   <chr>                                 <int>        <int> <chr>                       <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1 Finished Item                             0            1 Finished Item                  10     0    10
# 2 Subassembly 1                             1            2 Finished Item                  10     1    20
# 3 Component 1 Subassembly 1                 2            5 Finished Item                  10     1   100
# 4 Subassembly 2                             1            4 Finished Item                  10     2    40
# 5 Component 1 Subassembly 2                 2            2 Finished Item                  10     2    80
# 6 Component 1 Component 1 Subassembly 2     3            2 Finished Item                  10     2   160
```

### base R

```r
dat$L1 <- with(dat, ave(Level == 1, Parent.Item, FUN = cumsum))
dat$Qty <- with(dat, ave(seq_len(nrow(dat)), list(Parent.Item, L1), FUN = \(rn) {
  Parent.Qty.Forecast[rn] * sapply(Level[rn], \(lvl) prod(Quantity.Per[rn][Level[rn] <= lvl]))
}))
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
# should use setDT(dat) instead
as.data.table(dat
  )[, L1 := cumsum(Level == 1), by = .(Parent.Item) 
    ][, Qty := Parent.Qty.Forecast * sapply(Level, \(lvl) prod(Quantity.Per[Level <= lvl])),
      by = .(Parent.Item, L1) ]
```

---

Data

```r
### without 'Qty.Needed'
dat <- structure(list(Item = c("Finished Item", "Subassembly 1", "Component 1 Subassembly 1", "Subassembly 2", "Component 1 Subassembly 2", "Component 1 Component 1 Subassembly 2"), Level = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Quantity.Per = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L), Parent.Item = c("Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item"), Parent.Qty.Forecast = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
### with 'Qty.Needed`
dat <- structure(list(Item = c("Finished Item", "Subassembly 1", "Component 1 Subassembly 1", "Subassembly 2", "Component 1 Subassembly 2", "Component 1 Component 1 Subassembly 2"), Level = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Quantity.Per = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L), Parent.Item = c("Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item", "Finished Item"), Parent.Qty.Forecast = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Qty.Needed = c("(1x10) = 10", "(1x2x10)=20", "(1 x 2 x 5 x 10) = 100", "(1 x 4 x 10 ) = 40",  "(1 x 4 x 2 x 10 ) = 80", "(1 x 4 x 2 x 2 x 10 ) = 160")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans! This is beautiful. I think in dplyr I can add a column for the BOM using seq() and arrange to preserve order of rows for the BOM.